# getBoundingClientRect not refreshing on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a very odd problem.
http://codepen.io/tjmediative/pen/zKjPwN

This works in desktop browsers, but doesn't work at all on mobile.

```
function getElementVerticalInViewport (el) {
  // This gives us the vertical positioning for the element
  // This is just for jQuery compatibility
    if (typeof jQuery === "function" && el instanceof jQuery) {
        el = el[0];
    }

  // This is your main code. getBoundingClientRect is much more efficient.
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    //$("#mobile-text4").html("getElementVerticalInViewport="+document.getElementById("scroll-my-text").getBoundingClientRect().top);
    return rect.top;
}
```

getBoundingClientRect is not being refreshed at all when scrolling, which is very odd behaviour.

The commented html inject tag was to make sure the data gets refreshed. All is good on desktop, however on mobile the value is stuck to some weird number (808), and it gets fired whether the div is in the viewport or not.

Edit:
I'm trying to get a div's content modified through jquery depending on its position within the viewport. getBoundingClientRect gives me the data I need to check if the div is in the viewport, and its position relative to the viewport's edges. This works fine in the jQuery (check the codepen link above). However, on mobile browsers and devices, getBoundingClientRect is not updating at all when scrolling, therefore the content cannot be changed to its proper value. It seems getBoundingClientRect is unsupported or buggy, unless there's something wrong with how I am using it, but it works on non-mobile browsers just fine.

Comment: I don't understand your question. `getBoundingClientRect` has nothing do to with jQuery so I don't know why it's relevant.

Comment: Edited it for more detail, hope its clearer.